Can i ask for compensation or I can i request unemployment?
I do remote work and have a company desktop computer that was sent to me. The computer has no longer powered on since early March. I was able to tape it and rig it to work a few hours before it would turn off as I waited. Since then it has gone down completely.
IT told me three days ago I would get a replacement, however as of today nothing.
When I asked my director about downtime pay I was told we don't get anything and I could use my PTO. I did that for the first few days. But I can't continue doing so as I have health issue and kids issue I save that for.
I don't feel that is right to ask me to burn vacation time because the hardware has failed.
I am in the United States in Georgia for rhose rhat want it clear and a full time employee.
UPDATE
As of Monday (4/8) I sent an follow up to Human Resources to see if there is anything they can do about pay, since it's it's been over a month with my being unable to work due to their equipment's failure. They are trying to say they don't pay anytime you're not clocked in.  I have attached the policy they are saying covers this issue.
Question: How can I get them to pay something? It isn't  my fault I can't be productive without a working computer, or that the computer is malfunctioning.


You ignored questions on the last time you asked, and still didn't provide where are you country wise or whethere you are even an employee.

VTC - with the Policy photo - this has gone directly into a region of question we cannot answer. It depends on your state laws - but I that policy smells like BS to me - and wouldnt hold up in Court... But... To answer that question You need an employment lawyer familiar with your local Laws, precendents and the full company policy

@AidaPaul, It seems they tagged the country "United States". Personally, I think they should also say which state they're both in. Also, the term "PTO" and "employee" seems to imply that they're an employee, not a contractor. So for me, the question would be the kind of employee they are, are they full time or part time? When did they start? How many hours are they supposed to be working?

"Can I request unemployment ?" -- Do you mean to say you want your company to fire or lay off you so that you can get the unemployment benefits ? -- You can't get the unemployment benefits while working for a company, generally speaking.

I did say in the states and full time employee in post. I'm in united states GEORGIA to be clear. I work in the customer service field

Tried to edit for clarity and readability. Hopefully I didn't misrepresent what the author was trying to say. But since they are an hourly wage worker rather than on salary, I suspect that, like a young codfish, they are simply schrod.

It sure sounds illegal. It is illegal in large parts of Europe. The US, being what is is with labor laws, I am not so sure. I have seen shittier things being legal. You should get a lawyer, because if it is illegal, the company will not budge on just you telling them you read it on the internet.

If you are employed and you claim employment, you would be committing fraud because you are not unemployed. I am still wondering why this problem has gone on for a month. Have you not been clocked for over a month per company policy? Are you an exempt or nonexempt employee?

The document that you posted says that non-exempt employees are required to clock out of the time keeping system whenever there are IT or computer issues that prevent these employees from working. This means these non-exempt employees won't get paid whenever there are computer issues that prevent them from working (unless they take PTO).
By definition, “Non-exempt” is a term referring to employees who earn less than $684 per week. Here is the web page for more info.

I am not sure if you are an exempt or non-exempt employee.
There are 2 scenarios:

For non-exempt employees: The company will likely apply their policy (from the document that you post) to say that these non-exempt employees can't get paid when
there are computer issues that prevent them from working. If these employees want to get paid during these down time, they have to use their own PTO.
For exempt employees: The company must continue to pay these exempt employees whenever there are computer issues that prevent them from working. The company can't force these employees to take PTO during these down times. BTW, most of the time, exempt employees are also full-time salary employees, who don't need to clock in and clock out.


I am certain that the policy was never intended to cover a situation where an employee, as WFH, and their device stopped working more than a month ago. Something else is going on that isn't being shared.

Most companies wouldn't penalize even an exempt employee for a failure on the company's part. But most companies would try to replace faulty hardware in less than a month. I tend to agree that there's a puzzle piece we haven't got, either on the company's side or on the employee's.

I have a co worker I have been talking to. From what he is say many folks systems have gone down and they are facing the same thing I am. I made sure all questions have been on email to have a paper trail. Cause I'm use to companies that have these type issues paying until it's fix.

Wages and salary aren't always the same thing. It is possible to be a full-time 40-hour-week  employee but still be classified as getting hourly pay rather than a salary paid at specific amounts on specific dates. It sounds like your employer is claiming that your contract is based on hours worked.
Take your contract (you did save a copy, right? If not, ask HR to copy it for you) to a local lawyer with expertise in employment cases. They will be able to tell you whether the agreement you and they signed is hourly or salary.
If it's salary. you absolutely should be getting paid, and it's their responsibility to get you the right equipment, find work you can do without it, or pay you to twiddle your thumbs. You shouldn't have to burn personal time off for their inefficiencies. (Though in a better run company I might offer to do so, simply because I hate sitting around waiting for things to happen.) In the other hand, salaried workers usually don't get overtime pay.
If it's really an hourly wage -- which, as I said, does sometimes still happen, especially for folks in their very first year with a company -- then you may be out of luck. Though frankly if they can't give you work you should be looking for someone who can and will. A badly run company is usually not worth staying with. And next time read the contract carefully to make sure it does not permit this.
Can the law protect you? Gods only know; GET A LAWYER to find out. All we can do here is sympathize and guess, neither of which actually helps you.

I'm an hourly person and plan to look into legal options. I have been applying for other jobs also. I just have never worked for a company that does this.

Have you ever had a machine die on you before? I agree that they should have fixed it more quickly if they cared about what you were doing for them, but...

If you work for a company, and the company is supposed to provide you with the equipment necessary to do the job, and they don't do that, then you cannot be held liable for the work you didn't do. If you are an employee and have work hours, and you can show that you made a reasonable attempt to do the work but could not do so, then they have to pay you for the hours you are contracted for. This is just the same when you work from home as if you showed up to an office and found that your company computer didn't work there.
So let's look at this:

The company owes you wages for all of this time. Do not "ask if there is anything they can do about wages", tell them that they owe you money for your wages. If it doesn't show up tell them you will sue.
Don't take PTO. That's for the same reason as above. They owe you money if it's their fault you can't work.
Start every day by sending a message saying "I am ready to work but my computer still isn't working. If there is any useful work I can do without the computer let me know, but until then I will spend the day waiting for you to fix my computer." Send it several times a day. you should have done this every day since this thing started. I establishes the problem, keeps you in the minds of the company, and provides evidence that you were willing to work each day.
Consult a lawyer. Not paying you wages is usually a criminal offence. A lawyer will give the details. Getting actual wages paid may be tricky, but if it can be done a lawyer will know how.
Look for another job. You can do this while doing all of the above. If you find one take it. Don't worry about giving notice. If you haven't been paid for work you owe your company nothing.

This assumes you are in a country with a vaguely civilized employment system with semi-adequate employee protections - and yes I even include the US in this case. Being "at will" doesn't mean they can cheat you of your wages. If you are in India things may be different.
EDIT: I now see the contract you edited into the question. I still think there is a good chance they are breaking the law in every state of the US. But you should consult a lawyer to be sure. In any case, look for another job. You don't need their permission to do that since 1865.
